# Different views using UISegmentControl

Tags: ios7

If we are taking 4 segments in a Segment control can we present different ViewController for each segment?
Like --
For -- Segment 0  -- I want to present TableviewController
Segment 1 -- ViewController
Segmnent 2 --- ViewController1
Segment 3 -- ViewController3

If possible in this way please guide me...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I wrote [`SDCSegmentedViewController`](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCSegmentedViewController) for that purpose.